# Can I have multiple custom startup configurations in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

Currently I can only put programs to startup folder and after that all of them will launch every time when I turn on PC. But what if I want several configurations? For example first configuration for holidays with browser autoloading only and second cofiguration for weekdays with work programs autoload (email agent, Office programs, and so on). So I want to save configuration somewhere and before system load select from menu what list of autoload programs I want now.

Is it possible to configurate this in windows 7?

Comment: Standard Win 7 does not have this facility. I presume you are not talking about Win 7 HOME which you'll definitely have problems even finding good apps for this.   You'd have to look at third party apps to do this.

Comment: An idea: add in the registry: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run a programs that will ask you which profile you want, and ADD/REMOVE the keys accordingly (ie ADD programs you want to auto download or remove other keys if you don't want them to load). programs in the in the RunOnce key are run sequentially, so it should works. NB a big drawback of this approach: your PC will be stop in the loading process until you choose which configuration you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not two different users - "Holyday Joe" and "Working Tim" ?

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think this answer needs improvement. Maybe add some details, like how to add user accounts and how to configure startup programs?

Comment: And different rights, home folders data etc... Also what if I need to install a program only for me - install for all users or install it twice for *Holyday Joe* and *Working Tim*? Also what about manual copy shortcuts? It is not too easy-to-use, I think. :)